# Best free Image server for blogging website laravel 5.0

Tags: image, laravel-5

I am implementing a blogging website using laravel 5.1. I need to put all the images in another image server. AWS s3 will be costly after 1 year. As its a charity work, I need a free server. I have tried flickr ( https://github.com/dan-coulter/phpflickr ) but its not working. Any other suggestion?

Comment: How many images are we talking here? Maybe it is possible to just host it your self in the Laravel storage?

Comment: Images are actually uncountable. As its a blogging site, it can be crore @Maantje

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can try imgur. Official Documentation here ( https://api.imgur.com/#freeusage )